# How to execute dc.js renderlet or pretransition functions in dc-tableview.js without rerendering whole table?

Tags: javascript, datatables, tableview, dc.js

I am trying to conditionally format a **dc-tableview.js table**.

This **works for the first page** with following code:

```
tableView1.on('pretransition', function (tableView1) {
// tableView1.on('renderlet', function(tableView1){
  var SecretKPIs = tableView1.selectAll('td.SecretKPI');
  console.log('renderlet function 2');
  SecretKPIs.each(function (d, i){
    if (this.innerText >= MediumValueThreshhold && this.innerText < BadValueThreshhold){
      this.classList.add('MediumValueFont');
    } else if (this.innerText >= BadValueThreshhold){
      this.classList.add('BadValueFont');
    };
  })
})
```

When I **change to the next page** or change the sorting of a column - the values change but the conditional formating does not apply anymore.

**Any idea how I could apply the conditional formating again?**

If I use the render function `tableView1.render()` - the table does not apply the filter of the page or the sorting.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with dc-tableview internals, but it sounds like the library should either fire `pretransition` when the [page event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) happens, or you could probably listen to this event yourself, via the exposed [getDataTable](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview#object-getdatatable) property.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon - finally got it working! :)
It worked with the page event but I had to set a small timeout (`setTimeout`) because the page seemed not to be updated in time.

Comment: That's great! Yes, according to the document I linked, the `page` event is fired before paging happens; someone in the comments suggests listening to the `draw` event "to manipulate elements within records that are being re-drawn to the table". That should be a closer equivalent to `pretransition`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigation. Your answers are always a pleasure! :)
I will try this when I have time.
What I found in the internet is that the event `rowcallback` is often used for conditional formating. But unfortunately, this event **does not fire somehow** in my dc-tableview table. Even though it is an event in the library - probably I am doing something wrong...